# rails 5 carrierwave in polymorphic association undefined method cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, hidden-field

I'm usign Rails 5.1 and carrierwave 1.1.0.

In my association fotos belongs to prendas.

Here is my models:

```
class Prenda < ApplicationRecord

has_many :fotos, inverse_of: :prenda, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :fotos

validates :....

end
```

the fotos model:

```
class Foto < ApplicationRecord
mount_uploader :file, FileUploader

belongs_to :prenda, inverse_of: :fotos

validates :file, presence: true, file_size: { less_than: 1.megabytes }

end
```

And its controllers:

```
class PrendasController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index

  @prendas = Prenda.all

end

def show

  @prenda = Prenda.find(params[:id])

  @fotos = @prenda.fotos.all

end

def new

  @prenda = Prenda.new

  @foto = @prenda.fotos.build

end

.........

private

    def prenda_params

      params.require(:prenda).permit(:titulo, :tipo, fotos_attributes: [:file, :file_cache])

    end

end
```

......

```
class FotosController < ApplicationController

def index

  @fotos = Foto.all

end


def show

end

def new

  @foto = Foto.new

end

..........

private

  def foto_params

    params.require(:foto).permit(:file, :file_cache)

  end

end
```

And the form:

```
%= bootstrap_form_for @prenda do |f| %>
  <% if @prenda.errors.any? %>
    <%= f.alert_message "Favor correjir los errores debajo." %>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :titulo, 'Titulo' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :titulo %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :tipo, 'Tipo' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :tipo %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Fotos:</strong>
    <% if @fotos %>
       <% @fotos.each do |foto| %>
        <%= image_tag foto.file.thumb.url %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :file, 'Agregar Imágen' %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :file %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :file_cache %>  
  </p>

  <p> <%= f.submit "Guardar", class: "btn btn-primary"%> </p>
<% end %>
```

In this scenario I'am getting the error:

NoMethodError in Prendas#new

Showing /home/mateo/Tienda/app/views/prendas/_form.html.erb where line #55 raised:

undefined method `file_cache' for #Prenda:0x00000003a795b0

Please Help!.

What I'm doing wrong?

I see the error message is for the Parent object "Prenda" that hasn't got "fotos or files" but, how I should instantiate the @foto builded in the PrendasController in the form?

Thanks, Mateo.

Answer (score 0):

File is and field of Foto model and its being submitted via nested attributes so i think you should use this:

```
 <p>
  <%f.fields_for fotos_attributes do |foto| %>
    <%= foto.label :file, 'Agregar Imágen' %><br>
    <%= foto.file_field :file %>
    <%= foto.hidden_field :file_cache %> 
  <%end%> 
 </p>
```

and there is no need to build `@foto = @prenda.fotos.build` this.
you can try this. and the error is showing in line 55, so could you please show line 55 code.

please followup this tutorial [tut-1](https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/) and [tut-2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

thanks.

Comment: Thank you Anand for your explanation and the tutorials. This resolve my problem.

Comment: My line 55 was:     <%= f.hidden_field :file_cache %>  
It belong to the block: <p>
    <%= f.label :file, 'Agregar Imágen' %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :file %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :file_cache %>  
  </p>

Comment: I have another problem now. After bundle update I can't star rails. I'm getting the error:     .... => Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/carrierwave-1.2.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:45:in `block in <class:Railtie>': undefined method `include?' for :es:Symbol (NoMethodError)
I think this is somethig in relation with my spanish internationalization (:es:Symbol). This was ok until now. If I can't resolve it soon may be I open another issue here. Thank you Anand (Not Vishy? (Viswanathan)

Comment: if this issue came after bundle update then you can checkout gemfile.lock file.` git checkout Gemfile.lock`